# Apply an id if a table header has a specific string

Tags: jquery

I would like to apply an id to a table that has a specific string in the header. The table does not have any css tags, and I can't add them without doing it dynamically. 
This is my table:

```
<div id="primary" class="page">
<div class="inside">
<table border="10">
<tr><th>You may search for materials using the following:</th></tr>

<tr><td align="center"><a href="#">NAME</a></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center"><a href="#">TITLE</a></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center"><a href="#">SUBJECT</a></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center"><a href="#">WORD</a></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center"><a href="#">ISBN</a></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center"><a href="#">ISSN</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

I would like to apply an id of #mytable to any table that has string "you may search for materials" int he table header
I tried using an .addClass but I'm getting confused. I would appreciate any help, 
thanks

Comment: *I would like to apply an `id` of `#mytable` to any table* you realise that an `id` ***must*** be unique within the document, right?

Comment: This isn't what a table should be used for.  If you just want to format stuff, use CSS. Use tables to show tabular data.

Comment: With addClass you do not add `id`, but (as the function name says) `class`. Use `$('<your_selector_here>').attr('id','mytable')`. Be warned with using multiple ids in one document.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
$('table th:contains("You may search for materials using the following")')
    .closest('table').addClass('myTable');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rx7qU/).

Note that I'm adding a `class` name instead of an `id`, since your question implies that there may be multiple elements on the page that match that given condition.

I'd further suggest *not* using a `table` for this, since it's clearly *not* tabular data, but a list, therefore using a `ul` seems far more appropriate:

```
<ul>
    <li class="header">You may search for materials using the following:</li>
    <li><a href="#">NAME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TITLE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SUBJECT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">WORD</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ISBN</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ISSN</a></li>
</ul>
```

With the following CSS to approximate the look of your `table` presentation:

```
ul {
    width: 50%;
    border: 10px groove #666;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0.2em;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

li.header {
    font-weight: bold;
}

ul.myTable li.header {
    color: #f00;
}
```

and adapted jQuery:

```
$('li.header:contains("You may search for materials using the following")')
    .closest('ul').addClass('myTable');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rx7qU/2/).

References:

- [`addClass()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`closest()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`:contains()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an advanced selector like so:

```
$('th:contains("You may search for materials")').closest('table')
                                                .addClass('mytable');
```

Using classes her as IDs must be unique.

**Note:** `contains()` is case-sensitive.